# Clang linker not recognising -e option but GCC linker does

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang, ld, entry-point

I would like to use a Makefile to generate a binary that does unit tests for me. It takes all the object files of my program, as well a compiled tester object, and packages it all together. The issue is, I want to use a custom entry point inside the tester file instead of `main`.

So no problem, `ld` comes with a flag `-e` where I can specify said entry point. So inside of my Makefile I have written:

```
$(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -Wl,-e$(TEST_ENTRY) $(OBJDIR)/$(TEST_SUITE:.c=.o) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)-test
```

Taking care to note that I am doing all my linking with the `gcc` function so I have to pass my command to the linker with `-Wl`. This is where the problem begins:

Using `gcc` on Debian, this command works perfectly and my program runs as expected.

Using `clang` on MacOS, I am presented with the following error during compile time:

> ld: unknown option: -etester
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [test] Error 1

The Makefile is putting the entry point (named `tester`) with the argument without any space. As far as I know, this should be perfectly acceptable? After all, `gcc` accepts it.

If I add a space, it will assume `$(TEST_ENTRY)` is an argument for the compiler instead. I can avoid this with quotation marks. So I also tried the following:

```
-Wl,"-e $(TEST_ENTRY)"
```

However I get the same error

> ld: unknown option: -e tester

May I ask if anybody knows a solution that will allow clang to function correctly while not sabotaging the fact that it already works in gcc? Perhaps I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Function Name Mangling

This seems related to the function name mangling of clang. To avoid user-defined function name duplicated with intrinsic function names in libc or Sysmte.A, compiler mangle user-defined function names. for c language, usually, a '_' is added as prefix.

for example,

```
int test(..)
```

is mangled to

`_test` in clang compilation procedure.

#### Testing project:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}

int test(int argc, char const* argv[]){
  printf("hello test entry\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `clang helloworld.c -o helloworld`,
execution result:

```
╰─$ ./helloworld     
hello world
```

when compiled with `clang helloworld.c -o helloworld -e_test`,
execution result:

```
╰─$ ./helloworld     
hello test entry
```

refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling for more details or reply to ask.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer Simon however appending the _ does nothing. I continue to receive the same error: `ld: unknown option: --entry=_tester`.

Comment: @FinnRayment         
command:      
`clang helloworld.c -o helloworld  -e_test`

 **not** .  :        
`clang helloworld.c -o helloword --entry=_test` .    

note, no blank exists between `-e` and `_test`

please refer to `man clang` for detailed clang command usage, or reply to ask.

Comment: So it seems that I can bypass using `-Wl` altogether and just pass it straight to the `gcc` alias of clang. This also works on GNU `gcc`. The only problem I have now is the fact that clang is appending this extra `_` which I can do a check for that anyway. Can you please add your comment to the answer and I will mark it as correct? Thankyou for the help.

Comment: @FinnRayment  In fact, it is a very complex thing. This is related to `ABI: Application Binary Interface`. There are several different ABI standards defined along with the programming history,. ABI matters not only function name mangling ways, but also how function arguments passed in when invoke a `call` instruction, as well as stack balancing method and local variables ordering. Different compilers (or compiler versions) might use different ABI standards, I've tried clang-6.0 on ubuntu ( **-Wl,-etest** ), clang-8.0 on ubuntu (**-etest**), clang-10.0 on mac (**-e_test**).

Comment: Im also using clang-10.0 on Mac and if it requires different parameters for clang-6.0 and 8.0 then this is concerning. I'm migrating to `autoconf` anyway so this will solve all my long-term problems.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for `lld`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/lld-8/ld.lld-8.1.en.html) (the LLVM linker) says that the flag to specify an entry point is `--entry`.  So on MacOS you'll have to use an argument like `-Wl,--entry=$(TEST_ENTRY)` instead.

Comment: Same issue I'm afraid. Edit: Hang on I missed the `=`.

Comment: Yes, I still receive `ld: unknown option: --entry=tester`

Comment: I feel like `clang` isn't passing the arguments on to `lld` correctly.